# Calling Matlab function from Python

Tags: python, matlab, function, os.system

I'm trying to run matlab function from Python code. For doing do this i have written this simple code:

```
#!C:/Python3/python.exe

import os

os.chdir("C:/xampp/cgi-bin/")
os.system('matlab -r "logaritmic C:/xampp/htdocs/img/resim.jpg ,3"')
```

logaritmic function gets 2 variables, folder location and logaritmic coefficent.
when i run this script matlab runs, i can get output but wrongly. If i change the input(3) in function.m script, code works correctly. The problem is getting input wrongly. Now where is my fault why matlab gets '3' wrongly or doesnt get?
What i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that matlab get inputs as a string. So code runs wrongly. For solve this problem, the logaritmic function can be change. For example '3' string can be converted to integer in function.m script using x = str2num(str) method.

Answer (score 0):

i am definitely not a matlab guy, but i think you cannot pass parameters to your function (logaritmic) from the command line.

[This forum post](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97204-how-can-i-pass-input-parameters-when-running-matlab-in-batch-mode-in-windows) could help.

Cheers

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

If `logaritmic` is your function, the correct call shoud look like

```
logaritmic("C:/xampp/htdocs/img/resim.jpg",3)
```

This supposes that `logaritmic` has two arguments. Obviously you now need to properly escape the string in Python.

Comment: it doesn't work because code would be like this                         os.system('matlab -r "logaritmic ('C:/xampp/htdocs/img/resim.jpg ',3)"')   it means a lot of quotes are available